# Why it is returning PY_VAR0 instead of a number

Tags: python, tkinter, optionmenu

I'm trying to return a value after having selected it with Tkinter, but I keep getting `PY_VAR0`.

I have checked on the internet but the solution is to use `.get()`, which I have already done.

Does someone have an idea please?

```
from tkinter import *

def f1():
    fenetre1 = Tk()
    fenetre1.title("Ma fenetre")  # titre de la fenêtre

    texte3 = Label(fenetre1, text='Nombre de cases par ligne/colonne :')
    texte3.pack()

    listeoptions = []
    for i in range(10, 21):
        listeoptions.append(i)
    v = StringVar(fenetre1)
    v.set(listeoptions[0])
    w = OptionMenu(fenetre1, v, *listeoptions)
    w.pack()

    def ok():
        v.get()
        print(v)

    button = Button(fenetre1, text="Jouer", command=ok)
    button.pack(side=BOTTOM)
    fenetre1.mainloop()

f1()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are correct that the solution is to use `.get()`. However, you are currently not doing anything with the value returned by this method. Try printing it instead:

```
def ok():   
    print(v.get())
```

Comment: wow nice, how to reuse it after in my fonction ok()? Do I have to write v.get() every time?

Comment: @FloRaptor In that case, just save it to a variable: `val = v.get()`. You can then access it in following lines as `val`. If you need to access it from multiple functions, you may consider refactoring this code into a class and saving it as a class attribute.

Comment: yes of course, seems so easy right now... Thanks a lot!